# Persuade Visual studio not to break on unhandled exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2022

I want to run some code in debug mode. I do NOT want VS to break on any exceptions. My attempts to persuade it not to are failing. In particular, I unchecked every box under "Break When Thrown" in the "Exception Settings" window. What else do I need to do?

[image: DoNotBreakOnExceptions]

Comment: The place where this gets highly annoying is when using XUnit's Assert.Throws. The exception is handled, but it's not "user code". So VS breaks on it, even though everything is working as expected. My work-around is to write my own Assert.Throws-type methods. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw) we can know that try-catch or try-catch-finally blocks are used to handle thrown exceptions.
You can use try-catch to handle the thrown exceptions like this:

```
try  
    {  
        throw new InvalidOperationException();  
}  
catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot determine location type from provided inputs.");  
}
```

Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2015#setting-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) we can know that uncheck the exceptions in Exception Setting just work for handled exception.

If you checked the exceptions in Exception Setting, the handled exception will also throw an exception and break the debug.

Uncheck or check exceptions in Exception Setting is invalid if you just throw an exception without handling it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It may be that what I want is to tell VS to continue on unhandled exceptions, killing the thread if necessary? How can I do that?

Comment: I checked the official documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022 ). 
We can see that ” It may break execution in the following cases when: An exception is thrown that isn't handled.”

Comment: You can turn on Just My Code and choose Continue when unhandled in user code, the debugger will continue if that exception isn't handled in user code but is handled externally. But we still have to handle the exception finally. See this page(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022#BKMK_UserUnhandled ).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to go for a try-catch solution.
Try this:

In Debug->Exceptions dialog, uncheck the check box under the User-Unhandled column for whatever exception type you wish to eliminate, for example: Common Language Runtime Exceptions, and VS will stop breaking on these exceptions.

Comment: There's no debug -> exceptions in vs2022 =(